# Grouped barplot showing proportion: How to skip some bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a variable the can take on the values 0 or 1 for each entry in the data frame. At the same time, each of the values were generated in a certain condition.

Now, I want to plot the proportion of '1's per condition. Note, that the respective data entries in the two conditions are not balanced, i.e., condition 'a' could have 20 entries of 0 or 1, whereas condition 'b' could have 200 entries of 0 or 1.

Thanks to a few posts here, I have come this far:

```
x <- rbinom(378,1,.9)
cond <- rbinom(378,1,.7)+1
myDf <- data.frame(x,factor(cond,labels=c('a','b')))
names(myDf) <- c('val', 'cond')
g <- ggplot(data.frame(myDf),aes(x=val, fill=cond)) 


g + geom_histogram(aes(y=0.5*..density..), binwidth=0.5, position=position_dodge())
```

[image: example image]

If you inspect the plot, you quickly see that one set of bars is superfluous.

--> How can I skip the plotting the bars at x-axis tick 0? They are already represented with the bars at x-axis tick 1, because I am plotting proportions after all.

**Edit: If you have an idea, how the difference in proportions could be tested for significance, feel free to check out this related [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260595/test-two-binomial-distributions-overall-successes-failures-and-proportion-suc).**

Comment: I would calculate the proportions first, then use a 'simple' `geom_col`. `df <- aggregate(val ~ cond, myDf, function(x) sum(x)/length(x)); 
ggplot(df, aes(x = cond, y = val, fill = cond)) + geom_col()`. Perhaps the `fill` `aes` is redundant, because you have already mapped 'cond' to `x`.

Comment: That's a very good idea and it achieves exactly what I wanted. Thank you, but why don't you put it up as a 'real answer'? On a different note: The fill is redundant but helps for distinction without inspecting the X axis (I also have more plots in the same suit where the same colors are mapped to the conditions).

Comment: Great to hear that it worked the way you wished. Please feel free to add as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Henrik described in the comments to my question, the problem can be solved by calculating the proportions first and then plotting them using the geom_col().

Based on the code in the original question:

```
df <- aggregate(val ~ cond, myDf, function(x) sum(x)/length(x))

ggplot(df, aes(x = cond, y = val, fill = cond)) + geom_col()
```

[image]